# Is there any time limit for which record can be pending for approval?

Tags: approval-process

Lets say for a Standard object or Custom object's record has been submitted for approval on 11-Nov-2014.
Is there any upper bound on or before which record should be approved / rejected? or is it that the record will be in pending state forever?